# flash z-index problem

Tags: flash, z-index, wmode

I'd like to change order flash swf and popupwindow.
if the popupwindow opens . flash swf overlayed on popupwindow
how can I solve this problem.

I've found a solution about wmode.
but some blog said wmode is so danger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting the `wmode` to `opaque` or `transparent` is your only option to get it to respect the z-order of your html. this has some drawbacks as you've noticed, but it's all a tradeoff, the other option is to rearrange your gui so this won't happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.If don't you mind my question . Please tell me the specific disadvantages you pointed on wmode

Comment: The best way to thank people for their answers freddie is to accept and upvote them.

Comment: Also bravo grapefrukt, +1 for being able to interpret.