# Two iframes on the same HTML5 full screen

Tags: html

I am using HTML5's full screen capabilities to expand a youtube embedded video in an iframe.
What I need to do is to show another iframe with an image on top of the first one, while on full screen.
I am looking at z-index but without success.

Code sample:

```
<iframe src="smiley.png" id="image"></iframe>

<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player" align="center"></div><br>
<button onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false">Fullscreen</button>
```

Also (javascript to go fullscreen):

```
function goFullscreen(id) {
      // Get the element that we want to take into fullscreen mode
      var element = document.getElementById(id);

      if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {

        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {

        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
     }
    }
```

And finally (CSS):

```
.iframeclass {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; left: 0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
  }
  iframe.image {
    position: relative;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  iframe.player {
    position: relative;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is youtube video as you said, you can solve it by adding `wmode=transparent`, or `wmode=opaque`, in iframe code (HTML atrtributes, not CSS). I have that problem before so I found the solution.
Something like `<iframe ... ... wmode=transparent>`.

That's the problem with Flash actually, not YouTube only, I guess.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6226708/2157739) is the answer from Stack Overflow.